# How do I compile a .java with support for older versions of Java?

Tags: java, compilation, cross-platform

I want to compile my .java's (several) into one `.jar` that are compatible with at least `Java 1.6` and newer, preferably `Java 1.5` and newer versions of Java. (I have `Java 1.7.0_5`)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.veryant.com/support/phpkb/question.php?ID=57

Comment: `javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5  OverridingInternalExample.java` worked for me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you can set the version of compiler at compile time. And compile your java code into old versions of java.

From Oracle article : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

**Cross-Compilation Example**

Here we use javac to compile code that will run on a 1.4 VM.

```
% javac -target 1.4 -bootclasspath jdk1.4.2/lib/classes.zip \
             -extdirs "" OldCode.java
```

You might also need following parameter to set denote the version of your code.

```
-source release
```

-Specifies the version of source code accepted.

Comment: It might be however easier to use Java 1.4 Compiler from the beginning.

Comment: It seems one cannot set a `-source` version higher than the `-target` version. `$javac abc/def/HelloDriver.java -source 1.7 -target 1.4`
     `javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7`

Answer (score 30):

As of JDK 9, javac support a new option for cross-compiling

```
javac --release N ...
```

which is equivalent to

```
javac -source N -target N –bootclasspath rtN.jar
```

Comment: Compiling code for java 8 using the JDK 10 I ran the command `javac --release 8 Main.java ` The result was runnable on java 8.

Comment: Doesn't require an old version of JDK, compiles back as far as version 6 (JDK 10), and only the Unicode version is pulled from the more recent platform.

Comment: `Old` does not mean bad, especially when `new` means paid or limited features. Also incompatibility with `stable` and `free` does not mean good.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `javac -target 1.5 <source files>`.

If you're using a build system, Eclipse or some other IDE to build jars, please specify which one.

Comment: i have netbeans, but i can just use text files. How would i apply that into all .java's in a directory?

Comment: With netbeans right click on your project, go to properties and change the "Source/Binary format" from the dropdown towards the bottom of the dialog that opens

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the target version of the compiler lower than the build java version (all answers basically said that) but you should not: it is quite messy as it only works if you also supply the class libraries for the actual target version. If you do that you are much better off with simply using this old Java version to compile. Much cleaner and less stuff to setup. For Java 9 the options are a bit nicer but you still need an old JDK lying around for the rt.jar.

What you can do is in your ide and dedvelopment cycle use the `-target`/`-bootclasspath` trick to get faster compiler and better warnings, but IT and release builds then should be done with the target version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the newest version of the JDK and set the source level to 1.5 - as long as you don't use classes / methods that were introduced after 1.5 you should be ok for all versions of the JVM 1.5 and above:

-source 1.5

Answer (score 0):

The following command will compile all your java classes with java version 1.8 because by default your code compiled by the latest version which you have.

```
javac -source 1.8 -target 1.8  *.java
```