# Applets not working in Browser

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, browser

I have created simple Applet Example. I have successfully created compiled and run it eclipse, but when i try to run in any of the browsers it shows..

### ***unsupported major.minor version 52.0***

I think the problem here is that i have java SE 1.8 64 bit installed on the system but browser is 32 bit and plugin points to jre1.7 32 bit, i have installed that also still the same error.
If i forcefully try to compile my applet using 1.7 it show the following error.

---

### javac: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8

---

how should I resolve this...any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to not build applets as nobody wants to have browser Java now.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761/how-do-i-compile-a-java-with-support-for-older-versions-of-java) how you can buld with a lower target version.

Comment: Thanks all for taking time to view and resolve. I have resolved the problem by compiling Applet bye SDK 1.6 and ran it successfully on browsers. Actually SE1.8 is not supported by browsers yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it working by compiling with the lower version of Java.

You can use `javac -target 1.6 <source files>`

If you're using some IDE to build jars, please specify which one.

Please see [This](http://www.veryant.com/support/phpkb/question.php?ID=57) link for details.