# How maven-compiler-plugin builds

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have windows machine with two java SDK - 1.4.2_04 and 1.8.0_45. I have simple maven Java project in Eclipse Mars.

```
After maven project creation vizard my pom xml looked like:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>grr</groupId>
    <artifactId>arr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

When I tryed to run my application it crashed with error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: arr/ff (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:537)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
    Exception in thread "main"
```

Code:

```
package arr;

    public class ff {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

        }

    }
```

Then I have updated my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>grr</groupId>
    <artifactId>arr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.4.2_04</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And got project working!

How maven knows where to search for JDK? I suppose maven-compiler-plugin somehow does this. If I change java.version to 1.4.2_16 it still compiles. Why? I don't have 1.4.2_16 on my system.

Comment: By changing the `<source>` and `<target>` parameters, you don't change the JDK to be used, but options given to the JDK (probably your 1.8.0_45 here) so that it produces Java 4 compatible code. I guess the compiler plugin is smart enough to understand that `1.4.2_04` and `1.4.2_16` just mean `1.4`.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761/how-do-i-compile-a-java-with-support-for-older-versions-of-java

Comment: Here is a question to put this in a different light: Maven itself is a Java program. What Java runtime will be used to run Maven when you run the 'mvn' shell script?

Comment: What about running code then? Output in 1.4 and 1.8 cases generates strings 1.4.2_04 and 1.8.0_40 accordingly. That means in both case different JRE is used. How maven knows what JRE I have? Or it is also possible emulate 1.4 JRE with java 1.8?

Comment: Yes, you can compile to a 1.4 target with 1.8 JDK. It seems that Maven is using 1.8 JDK and you run the app with the 1.4 one.

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0544.html), minor version `49` is from `1.5` compiled code.
That's because by default, `<source>` and `<target>` in maven compiler plugin is `1.5`. So you get that error when running your app with `1.4` JDK.

As long as you set `<source>` and `<target>` to `1.4`, your compiled code is compatible with `1.4` environment.

In your case, it seems that maven is using `1.8` JDK, probably configured as `JAVA_HOME` but you are running your app with the `1.4`JDK.