# Issue with running JAR in Windows, works fine in Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, testing, jar

I am stuck on the following error. I don't know what type of error it is.  What should I do?

> C:\Users\shehzad\Desktop\Software>java -jar Untitled.jar
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: FrontEnd/MainWindow : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)

**Scenario is**: I developed software that works fine in Ubuntu 14.04 Lts. It's JAR also works in Ubuntu, but when I tried this JAR
in Windows 7 it shows the above error.

Ubuntu Java version: 1.8.0_101

Windows Java version: 1.7.0_79

Comment: It looks like this has nothing to do with OS but with Java versions. You compiled it using Java 8 but trying to run on Java 7. Try to compile your code for older version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761/how-do-i-compile-a-java-with-support-for-older-versions-of-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class `version 52.0` means it requires Java 8 to run. You should for security reasons update your Windows Java anyway, so its time to go to Java 8. If you need Java 7 for something you can keep it as a private installation, but make sure the "javapath" as configured by the registry points to Java 8.

You can also start in a command window or via explorer link the right Java.exe without installing it as public version like this:

```
"c:\Program Files\java\jdk_1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe" -jar app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jar file is compiled using 8u101 (major.minor version 52.0) and your trying to run on 7u79. Hence you end up in Unsupported major.minor version 52.0.upgrade your java to 8u101.