# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: `bad major version at offset=6` source JRE- 1.6

Tags: java, class

I am compiling a java program which is giving me the following error :

```
The java class could not be loaded. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: `bad major version at offset=6`
```

Now generally,if you compile with source compatible 1.6 you need JRE 6 to execute the program. but right now my class file is compiled in 1.7 and my JRE version is 1.6.

I am not using eclipse or any tool but using a host type shell script to execute the program.

Is there any way to resolve this issue without changing the JRE version ?

Comment: You can try this answer [how do i compile a .java with support for older versions of-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761/how-do-i-compile-a-java-with-support-for-older-versions-of-java)

Comment: That would work if i have the source file. I do not have the java file

Comment: you need to change your question then, because you are not compiling a Java program at all, you are trying to run a compiled Java program with an older JRE.

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: `bad major version at** occurs when you compile your file in higher version and your JRE is lower than compiled file

```
% javac -target 1.4 -bootclasspath jdk1.4.2/lib/classes.zip \
             -extdirs "" OldCode.java
```

ref :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html