# Java JDK is not compatible with JRE

Tags: java, swing

I'm coding an Java Swing app on Intellij IDEA using JDK 21, I downloaded it on Oracle website, it just run fine with IDE or jar file, but when I installed JRE 8u391 (also in Oracle website), I clicked on jar file, it said:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

but if I used "java -jar" command, it would say:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: test/Program has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0.

Both JDK and JRE are latest on Oracle website, what should I do to run it with JRE?

With command "java -version":

> java version "1.8.0_51"

With command "javac -version":

> javac 21.0.1

Comment: You cannot run a class compiled on a higher version of Java and run in a lower version. Remove Java 1.8 and run using Java 21. Also, are you sure you are using Java 21 for compiling? The class version 55 doesn't match Java 21 it matches Java 11.

Comment: Also see [How do I compile a .java with support for older versions of Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364761/how-do-i-compile-a-java-with-support-for-older-versions-of-java).

Comment: **Oracle does not release JRE packages for Java 11 up.** (And no longer offers 9 and 10 at all.) You are supposed to either get the JDK and tailor your own JRE using jlink, or use another OpenJDK builder who still does JRE packages, such as AdoptOpenJDK-now-Adoptium Temurin, Azul Zulu, IBM Semeru, or major Linux distros (only for themselves) like Debian/Ubuntu/Mint and RedHat/Fedora. Semidupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111921/how-can-i-get-java-11-run-time-environment-working-since-there-is-no-more-jre-11 .